# Close android app and it's running features on Home press

Tags: java, android

I know all of you say that you shouldn't force your app to close, but I kinda need it. 
The thing is, my app has vibrate and sound (mediaplayer) at the same time. So when the user presses "Home", it should stop those two and "close the app down". Right now NOTHING happens when I press Home - actually it kinda freezes (but sound and vibrate goes on) - until the app crashes.

```
                        if (mpButtonClick.isPlaying())
                    {mpButtonClick.pause();
                    mpButtonClick.seekTo(0);

                    vibr.cancel();
                    }

                    else
                    {

                    mpButtonClick.start();
                    int length = mpButtonClick.getDuration();
                    vibr.vibrate(length);

                    }
```

I also have a onDestroy and onBackPressed (they're similar):

```
                    mpButtonClick.stop();
            vibr.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
        System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);

                System.exit(0);
```

onBackPressed works perfectly. But "Home"-button crashes. 
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> I know all of you say that you shouldn't force your app to close, but I kinda need it.

No, you do not.

> So when the user presses "Home", it should stop those two

Stop the media playback and vibration in `onPause()` or `onStop()`.

> But "Home"-button crashes. Any ideas?

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash. Consider opening up a fresh question with details of the stack trace, along with the associated source code, so people can help you with this crash.

Comment: Just added onPause and onStop. 
Just looked at the LogCat - understood nothing. 
Going to make a new question with the LogCat. 

Thanks.